# site collection admin does not have permission to access web app

Tags: 2007, permissions, site-collection

I have a SharePoint web app (let's say http:// providers), wherever I try to access this app (which only contains the root site collection) I get an "You are not authorized to view this page" IIS error.

Now I only have a couple of users who get access (but no Full Control permissions) on the site.

I changed the primary site collection administrator to my user account, then I modified the web app directive from the central administration and added my account with Full Control permissions and the error still appears.

What can I do to have acccess to this site? Should I restart IIS service or something to make it to work properly?

Comment: IIS restart shouldn't be needed but if its a development machine then give it a go

Comment: Unfortunately, it is our production server. We have about 800 users now and it is not feasible to restart service until tommorrow. I will keep checking what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out that the directory account under which SharePoint services run ended up being blocked from logging into the SharePoint servers (both WFE and database). So enabling it allowed us to resolve the problem.